# Characteristic time scale in floquet system?

Tags: scales, floquet-theory

In Floquet formalism, we have quasi-energy spectrum instead of energy spectrum. However, if we have a driving force with a low frequency, we shall be able to use adiabatic approximation and regard the dispersion relation as E=E(k,t), thus no more quasi-energy spectrum.

My question is , what is the characteristic time scale in floquet system? Or under what condition the quasi-energy spectrum can be observed?  I guess there are at least two.

1. Experimental technique. Like APRES , the coupling time between injecting photon and band electron.
2. Some feature in floquet system itself. I'm not sure what it is.

I think we can discuss WITHOUT thermalization here, since the question is already well defined.